# How to find an item from an IReadOnlyList<T>?

Tags: c#

I changed my property type from a `List<T>` to `IReadOnlyList<T>`, but I was using the `List<T>.Find()` method and now the compiler gives `error CS1061: 'IReadOnlyList<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Find' and no accessible extension method 'Find' accepting a first argument of type 'IReadOnlyList<T>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. How can I find an item from an `IReadOnlyList<T>`?

Answer (score 9):

`IReadOnlyList<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, you can use `IEnumerable<T>.FirstOrDefault()` to replace `List<T>.Find()`.